# What is the most Pythonic way to convert a valid json file to a string?

Tags: python

Below is what I'm doing currently, just wondering if there is a better way.

```
with open("sample.json", "r") as fp:
    json_dict = json.load(fp)
json_string = json.dumps(json_dict)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
with open("sample.json") as f:
    json_string = f.read()
```

No need to parse and unparse it.

If you need to raise an exception on invalid JSON, you can parse the string and skip the work of unparsing it:

```
with open("sample.json") as f:
    json_string = f.read()
json.loads(json_string) # Raises an exception if the JSON is invalid.
```

Comment: The `json.load` part might be needed to make sure the file contains valid JSON data

Comment: @Francisco: The question doesn't say anything about what should happen with files that don't contain valid JSON.

Comment: But the title is asking about valid JSON files.

Comment: @kirkpatt: That seems to just mean that the input will always be a valid JSON file, not that we need to validate it ourselves.

Comment: @user2357112 I took the question to mean how to decode a JSON file into a python string, not just put un-converted JSON into a string. I suppose that should be clarified.

Comment: @kirkpatt He already seems to know that it is a valid JSON file. secondly he wants a `str`. why do you assume that he is going to serialize it back to JSON.

Comment: @CPanda I don't, I assumed that he wanted a file with valid JSON to be converted into a python dict, then into a string.

Comment: @kirkpatt: The question just says he wants a string. The code goes through a dict, but it doesn't need to.

Answer (score 1):

Json file is just a regular file. You `open()` it and `read()` it. It will give you a `str`. If you want to make sure it contains valid JSON, put the `load` part of the above code in a `try/except` block.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's Pythonic or just pointless but you could also do this if validation is part of your requirements:

```
import json    
# I'm fully aware of the missing "ẁith" or "close" in the line below
json_string = json.dumps(json.load(open('sample.json')))
```

Otherwise, user2357112 already said it: *"No need to parse and unparse it."*

Comment: add the 'with' block if you feel that closing the file handle is necessary, but otherwise, yeah, this is pretty much it.

Comment: Pythonic or not. Your code is incomplete. where is `close`? Using a context manager is the best idea.

Comment: @CPanda Yeah, I was thinking that myself but how would you close the file here?

Comment: @WayneWerner Yeah, I always use `with` to avoid having to deal with closing files but I'm actually not sure how one closes a file in this situation. How would I find the handle? *Is* there a handle?

Comment: @jDo I think it would be something like this (Somebody feel free to correct me if wrong): `with open('sample.json) as fp: 
json_strong = jsondumps(json.load(fp))`

Comment: @kirkpatt I know how to use `with` (context manager) and it's normally the preferred way of handling files; the code I posted is just for fun/variation (I wouldn't use it). I was just asking if there's some way of obtaining a handle to an open file that has no variable/handle assigned to it in the first place *without* using `with`. If not, what happens to it? Does it just linger? Can it be closed? When does the garbage collector kick in if ever? I need to read...  Btw. your code is probably the best option/compromise.

Comment: @jDo Mine is probably a good way to do it if there was a need to parse and unparse it, but that's just a silly solution for this problem. And I think `with` is the only way to, well, do what `with` does.

Comment: You *can*, because a filehandle is just an integer on Linux (honestly I don't know about Windows. I'd actually expect opening the same file twice on Windows to die badly) if you know what the integer is to the file you can re-obtain a handle to the file with `open(file_int)`. I made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/d25e278c6f6d613fdc98ab1f330ebb8a) with some experiments to show how that works.

Comment: @WayneWerner Cool. Thanks for taking the time to write that gist and explain! I'll have to check it out later. Btw. I'm on Linux too and `lsof` does not show any open files when I run `json.dumps(json.load(open('sample.json')))` even though I don't call close but it does show the open file if I only write `open("sample-json", "r")`. I guess it means that the code I posted here auto-closes the file on Ubuntu 15 (I don't know why though).

Comment: Probably just the garbage collector. I noticed similar behavior that I noted in my gist. AFAIK that should be treated as an accident (like a `dict` printing in the same order twice), not something to be relied on as a feature.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it right. You probably can find some libraries with different implementations for performance or memory optimization specifics. The python standard is reliable, cover most of the cases, is assured to compatible to other platforms and is simple. It cannot get more pythonic than that.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're doing it is probably fine if you just need to have it raise an Exception for invalid JSON. However, if you want to make sure that you're not changing the file at all you could try something like this:

```
import json

with open("sample.json") as fp:
     json_string = fp.read()
json.loads(json_string)
```

It will still raise a ValueError if it is invalid JSON, and you know that you haven't changed the data at all.  If you're wondering what may change, off the top of my head: the order of dict items, and whitespace, Not to mention if there are duplicate keys in the JSON.